# How to check that all files in a file system are can be read without errors?

Tags: linux, backup, ext4, hardlink, check-disk

I'm using an external hard drive with an ext4 file system to make backups. The backup software I use (faubackup) copies the file hierarchy 1:1 into a timestamp-named folder on the hard drive, and makes incremental backups in such a way that it hardlinks new copies of files whose contents have not changed to the same file in the corresponding subfolder of the previous backup. Since I recently had a backup drive die on me, I now want to make sure that all the files written can actually be read without I/O error, so I know I can rely on my backup.

One way to do so would be to read the whole partition, e.g. by `dd`'ing it to `/dev/null`. However, the disk is 3TB large, and doing so would take about 7 hours (via USB 3.0).

Another way would be to use `e2fsck` with the `-c` option, but this also takes ages.

I'm thinking it should be possible to speed the process up by not checking the whole disk, but only the files, which is only a fraction of the whole disk size. This could be done e.g. by writing all files to a tar archive which is not written to disk, but sent to `/dev/null`. Here the problem is the hard linking: If I have say 10 incremental backups, the storage for that is again just a fraction of the disk, but it appears to be about 10 times larger than that.

*My question:* Is there a way to read only the files on the disk, and only one in each set of files hard linking to the same storage space? Or is there a way to make `e2fsck -c` or something similar only check the used parts of the file system (allocated blocks)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GNU tar does not copy the content of hard linked files multiple times. Read the first answer to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43037/dereferencing-hard-links) or the [official documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/hard-links.html) on this topic.  You can test this by piping the output (the archive) of *tar* through *wc*: `tar cf - -C <mountpoint of your disk> . | wc -c` and verify the archive size in bytes (you can compare this to the result with the *tar* option `--hard-dereference`).